# Why is there an extra folder in my file path?

Tags: magento2.3.1, requirejs-config.js

I am getting 404 errors for my javascript. I have ran static content deploy and all of the other commands that are recommended to clear this error but it doesn't matter. An example of my issue is this file-

/static/version1562689420/frontend/theme/themechildchild/en_US/Magento_Search/form-mini.min.js

shows as a 404 on the frontend.

When I look in my actual files that file does not exist but this one does-

/static/version1562689420/frontend/theme/themechildchild/en_US/Magento_Search/js/form-mini.min.js

What would cause that extra /js/ in the file path?

The only require js file I have is this one-

```
var config = {
paths: {
    slick: 'js/slick.min',
    slaask: 'js/customscript'
},
shim: {
    slick: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    menu: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check **deployed_version.txt** is exist under **pub/static** which contain version number. If not exist create **deployed_version.txt** and run static deploy command and clear cache.

**OR**

In **core_config_data** table change **dev/static/sign** to 0

Comment: It exists. The only thing in the file is a version number.

Comment: I changed the dev/static/sign and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You may give try by removing the version number from the URL

- open your Magento database and run this query to remove the version number from the path

  `insert core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);`
- after this clear cache

  `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*`
- Than deploy static content

  `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: I get the same errors as before after following these exact same steps.